# how to access forEach in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

Brand new here sorry if I do something wrong. 
      Here is my js fiddle     https://jsfiddle.net/phorton/2rdyj9oe/2/

I am trying to convert this to angular. I am stuck on trying to capture each 
numCoins value.

```
this.calcAmount = function(amount) {
    amount = amount * 100
    var coins = [
        {name: 'quarters', value: 25}, 
        {name: 'dimes', value: 10},
        {name: 'nickles', value: 5}, 
        {name: 'pennies', value: 1}]

    coins.forEach(function (coin) {
      var numCoins = Math.floor(amount / coin.value)
      this[coin.name] = numCoins
      amount -= (numCoins * coin.value)
})
```

}
 The top part of my js fiddle works putting the values out in console.log.
I need to store each iteration of numCoins and have it update each value on angluarjs. I am really lost sorry.

Comment: Could you please explain this `this[coin.name] = numCoins`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest initializing your `coins` array outside of the `calcAmount` function. You can also add an `amount` field to your `coin` objects and store the amount you are calculating there, as you are iterating the array. You can use this to display the results.

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpgoette/q51o7rsm/